# Where is Inara during "Serenity"?

Tags: firefly, serenity

In Firefly,

> when Inara is planning to leave Serenity, and she first tells Mal,

she says:

> INARA (cont'd) 
>  There's something that I... that I should have done a long while ago. And I'm sorry -- for both of us -- that it took me this long.
>  
>  INARA 
>  
>  I'm leaving.

Then the episode ends. It doesn't say where she is going to leave to, and (as far as I can remember) it doesn't say it in the episodes after that episode (*[Heart of Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_of_Gold_%28Firefly%29)*) either. Then, in "Serenity", Inara is at some school, where she prays (which doesn't seem like her, but it is also all we see her do there). So, is she at a companion school? It doesn't seem like it is, with the religious things. Also, Inara had already completed training for being a companion.

> "On Sihnon, we started training at twelve, years of discipline and preparation before the physical act of pleasure was even mentioned. Control was the first lesson, and the last."- Inara Serra explaining how much studying is involved with being a Companion.

So again: Where was Inara during "Serenity"?

Comment: Just a note - in the past (especially ancient Greece / Rome and similar), "companions" were often associated with churches (well, temples). So your assumption that companion schools would not be in a religious environment is flawed even in our own history, not just the world of Firefly / Serenity. A lot of rituals and similar also involve sexuality, orgies and similar - the connection has been there long before Judaism came along and said it's forbidden (with exceptions, of course :P).

Comment: i  meant that it did not seem like Inara, not that it wasn't like a companion.

Comment: We also know from Heart of Gold that a companion never stops training.

Comment: What do you mean by *during "serenity"* (is it a reference to the film's title, the ship's name or something else)?

Comment: Inara mentions praying for Mal and the crew in the pilot.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [film script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Serenity.pdf) lists it as "***Companion Training House***"

> A WOMAN'S VOICE (V.O.): They love you.
>
> EXT. **COMPANION TRAINING HOUSE** - DUSK
>
> Inara looks out at the mountains. The space she's in resembles a
>   Tibetan monastery, if slightly more opulent.
>
> Widen to see she is with SHEYDRA, a somewhat older Companion, the
>   woman whose voice we heard. She hands Inara a drink.
>
> **SHEYDRA:** *The girls. They've learned more from you these last months
>   than the rest of us could show them in two years.*

The clear implication is that this is where would-be companions are being trained before being officially sanctioned. Inara is evidently working there as a *tutor* for the latest batch of young recruits. The training house itself is apparently on the edge of the core worlds.